# how to add a if confition to a mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to add an if statement to a mysql query so that it checks the user exists from a table called ptb_users in the user_id column before the query runs.

users can write on other users walls and before a user can write on a users wall / before the query inserts into ptb_wallposts, i want it to check that the from_user_id = the ptb_users.user_id.

i am trying to do this but i get syntax errors all over my page can someone please can someone show me how i would need to structure this:

```
 <?php 
// check if the review form has been sent
if(isset($_POST['review_content']))
{
    $content = $_POST['review_content'];
        //We remove slashes depending on the configuration
        if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        {
                $content = stripslashes($content);
        }
        //We check if all the fields are filled
        if($_POST['review_content']!='')
        {
```

if exists (select user_id from ptb_users where user_id = @id)
begin

```
            {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO ptb_wallposts (id, from_user_id, to_user_id, content) VALUES (NULL, '".$_SESSION['user_id']."', '".$profile_id."', '".$content."');";
            mysql_query($sql, $connection);

            $_SESSION['message']="<div class=\"infobox-wallpost\"><strong>Wall Post Added</strong> - Your comment was posted to {$profile[2]}'s wall.</div><div class=\"infobox-close4\"></div>"; 
header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");


        } }
}
```

end
else
begin
echo "error user doesnt exist"
end

```
?>
```

Comment: Please, before you do *anything* else, read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid serious career damaging [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Do not use `mysql_query` in new code, it's dangerous, deprecated, and will be removed from future versions of PHP. [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) takes only half an hour [to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/), so unless you're saddled with some legacy project, use that instead.

Comment: Is there any reason why you're building this app from scratch instead of starting with [a popular framework](http://www.phpframeworks.com/top-10-php-frameworks/)? You're going to make innumerable mistakes and will have to reinvent things that have already been coded, packaged and documented by experts.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of if statement (from MySQL Reference)

```
IF search_condition THEN statement_list
[ELSEIF search_condition THEN statement_list] ...
[ELSE statement_list]
END IF
```

Let me explain a little more better, i'll compare between PHP and SQL if statements

PHP:

```
IF(variable > 0){
   anything..     
}
```

SQL:

```
IF variable > 0 THEN anything..
```

**Read more:[MySQL Reference - IF STATEMENT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html)**

Comment: Doing the `IF` inside of MySQL seems like a lost cause. This is application logic.